# Using DSE Hadoop/Mahout, NoClassDef of org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: maven, hadoop, mahout, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Trying to run a simple hadoop job, but hadoop is throwing a NoClassDef on "org/w3c/dom/Document"

I'm trying to run the basic examples from the "Mahout In Action" book (https://github.com/tdunning/MiA).

I do this using nearly the same maven setup but tooled for cassandra use rather than a file data model.

But, when I try to run the *-job.jar, it spits a NoClassDef from the datastax/hadoop end.

I'm using 1.0.5-dse of the driver as that's the only one that supports the current DSE version of Cassandra(1.2.1) if that helps at all though the issue seems to be deeper.

Attached is a gist with more info included.
There is the maven file, this brief overview, and the console output.

https://gist.github.com/zmarcantel/8d56ae4378247bc39be4

Thanks

Comment: Please provide detail step by step information to reproduce the issue. This may be a missing feature in DSE, so once we can reproduce it, we may be able to provide a fix.

Answer (score 0):

try dropping the jar file for class of org.w3c.dom.Document to $DSE/resource/hadoop/lib/ folder as a work around.